# Java + Jersey list of entities in input of webservice

Tags: java, arrays, web-services, entity, jersey

I need to receive a list of JSON entity as input to my WS.

Here my entity definition:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class ContactClass {
    public String action;
    public Long userId;
    public String phone;
    public String fbId;
}
```

here my WS function definition:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{userId}/adBook")
public String synchAdBookContacts(@PathParam("userId") Long userId, ArrayList<ContactClass> contacts)
```

Removing ArrayList<> It works fine, but I need an array of ContactClass as input.

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

**Update:**
Finally I found the solution, here the article that have solved my issue:
https://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/missing_brackets_at_json_one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bean 1:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contact {
   private String name;
   private String phoneNumber;


// Getters, setters, default constructor
}
```

Bean 2:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contacts {
   private List<Contact> contacts;

   //Getter for contacts
   @XMLElement(name = "listContacts")
   public List<Contact> getContacts() {
....


// Getters, setters, default constructor
}
```

You Json fiel should have the following format:

```
"listContacts":[{"json for contact1"},{"json for contact2"},{"json for contact3"}...]
```

Your Resource:

```
@PUT
@Path("/{userId}/adBook")
public String synchAdBookContacts(@PathParam("userId") Long userId, Contacts contacts) {
//Here you can get your contacts contacts.
```

Answer (score 0):

Deserializing to a list should work just fine. The following code works with RESTeasy + Jackson:

Bean:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Contact implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 2075967128376374506L;

   private String name;
   private String phoneNumber;

   // Getters, setters, default constructor
}
```

Resource:

```
@Path("/othertest")
public class AnotherTestResource {

   @POST
   @Path("/list/{id}")
   @Produces("application/json")
   @Consumes("application/json")
   public Response requestWithList(@PathParam("id") String id,
         List<Contact> contacts) {
      return Response.ok("Hello World: " + contacts.size()).build();
   }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't works...same issue.... _The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request)._ Here the payload: `[{"action":"add","userId":120,"phone":"322222"},{"action":"add","userId":120,"phone":"222211112"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Annotating your synchAdBookContacts method with @Consumes("application/json") should do it. Which JAX-RS implementation are you using and what error are you exactly getting?

Comment: I'm using Jersey, Consumes correctly set
I get a Status 400 - Bad Request (The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Bad Request).)